# WCF - Can the callback interface specified as a generic one?

Tags: c#, wcf, duplex

Consider that I am gonna create one generic interface for subscribing and unsubscribing to a duplex service, for ex:

```
[servicecontract(CallbackContract=typeof(ICallbackService))]
public interface IService
{
 [operationcontract]
 void sub();
 [operationcontract]
 void unsub();
}

public interface ICallbackService
{
[operationcontract(isoneway=true)]
void senddata(object data);
}

public interface IFirstService:IService{}
public interface ISecondService:IService{}
```

And on the client side while creating duplex channel instance, i have my callback instance as

```
class callbackclass:ICallbackService{
public void senddata(object d){}
}
```

and when using

```
DuplexChannelFactory<IFirstService> fact=new DuplexChannelFactory<IFirstService>(new instancecontext(new callbackclass()),new wsdualhttpbinding(),"address");
var chan=fact.CreateChannel();
```

I am facing a issue saying the contract IFirstService doesnt define any operations.Can any one help with this kind of scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't. It's not possible to do that, as soap does not support this. [Please read this article](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/79585667-6b97-4ce4-93fa-3a4dcc7a9b86/wcf-and-generics?forum=wcf).

Comment: But It worked when i created the proxy of parent interface type, i.e IService  in this case...